# Postgresql does not run psqrlc.conf file on startup windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, default

I have a file:
`%appdata%/postgresql/psqlrc.conf`

and in the file is one single line:
`set CLIENT_ENCODING to 'UTF8';`

I was expecting that on running

```
psql -U postgres
```

in the command line, I would connect to the server, and have the client_encoding set to UTF8 however, I find:

```
postgres=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 WIN1252
(1 row)
```

I would very much like my client encoding to be, by default, UTF8 in order to match the server

```
postgres=# show server_encoding;
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Does anyone know how what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Is that a typo in your question, or is this the actual filename?  `%appdata%/postgresql/psqrlc.conf`

Comment: Works for me. Is `psql` maybe a batch that does something else? What does `where psql` give you?

Comment: C:\program files\PostGRESQL\12\bin\psql.exe